# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

This code should return the name of the city in a card title which is defined in my other file but throwing an error.

Codes:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Body from './Body';

class Weather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weather: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${this.props.api}&q=Jaipur&aqi=no`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      weather: parsedData.weather,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.weather.map((element) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <Body city={element.location.name} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: What is the value of `parsedData.weather` that you are updating `this.state.weather` to? Is it an array?

Comment: yes this will store an array of all my weather details fetched from the api

Comment: Please show us the value of `parsedData`. From what I can tell, `this.state.weather` is a defined array on the initial render, so somehow after you fetch data and update state, `this.state.weather` is no longer defined. This is why you can't read `.map` or `.length` and an error is thrown. If I had your `this.props.api` value I'd just reproduce this myself and see what the response value is.

Answer (score 6):

##### The Problem:

your **weather** array is empty before the API call so using `this.state.weather.map` will cause the error.

##### The Solution:

There are two important things before using the `map` with **arrayes**:

1. check for the **definition** of the array (is the array defined and exists?)
2. check its **length** (is the array has some content?)

#### First

check its declaration/definition by a simple `if` statement:

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData) {
    myArrayOfData.map(
      // rest of the codes ...
    )
  }
}
```

Or with using `?` shorthanded of `if`

```
{
  myArrayOfData?.map(
    // rest of the codes ...
  )
}
```

#### Second

check for the contents of the array and use the `map` function after checking its **length** (which tells you the data has arrived from the API call etc. and is ready to process)

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData) {
    if(myArrayOfData.length > 0) {
     myArrayOfData.map(
        // rest of the codes ...
     )
    }
  }
}
```

#### Finally:

while the above snippet works properly, you can simplify it by checking both `if` conditions together:

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData?.length > 0) {
     myArrayOfData.map(
        // rest of the codes ...
     )
  }
}
```

So, simply make some changes in the return of `Weather` component:

```
<div className="row">
  {
    if(this.state.weather?.length > 0) {
      this.state.weather.map((element) => {
        return (
          <div className="col-md-4" key={element.id}>  // also don't forget about the passing a unique value as key property
            <Body city={element.location.name}/>
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
  }
</div>
```

##### Optional:

In real-world examples, you may need to show some loading components while the data is fetching.

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData?.length > 0) {
    myArrayOfData.map(
      // rest of the codes ...
    )
  } else {
    <Loading />
  }
}
```

###### Be Aware

```
const anEmptyArray  = []

if(anEmptyArray){
  // rest of the codes ...
}
```

The result of comparison on `if(anEmptyArray)` is always `true` with an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is just to add "this.state.weather &&" before map method, first it will make sure that "this.state.weather" is defined and then run the code, example is below

```js
{this.state.weather && this.state.weather.map((element) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <Body city={element.location.name} />
              </div>
            );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make an assumption that `parsedData.weather` have correct data type. You should make a conditional logic, to check `this.state.weather` should have a value from API.

Here's an example

```
 render() {
    const { weather } = this.state; // Access the state `weather`
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                     { /* This way use conditional ternary operator */ }
                    {weather.length ? weather.map((element) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <Body city={element.location.name}/>
                            </div>
                        );
                    }) : <span>Loading...</span>}
                </div>

            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is raising a error that => TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') ;

Comment: Yes I know it, but I mean the process is Asynchronous. So that's why the value is undefined

Comment: how do fix that ??

Comment: You must await asynchronous process, until you get the value. And then you can  render the element